# How does this variable escaping work in a systemd unit file?

Tags: bash, systemd, coreos

I have a fairly simple unit file for a discovery sidekick service for a server instance I'm running on CoreOS. The unit file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Discovery for frontend server (instance %i)
BindsTo=frontend@%i.service
After=frontend@%i.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/environment
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c ' \
    while true; do \
        export PORT=$(docker port frontend%i 80 | sed s/.*://); \
        etcdctl set /services/frontend/%i "${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:$PORT" --ttl 60; \
        sleep 45; \
    done'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/etcdctl rm /services/frontend/%i

[X-Fleet]
MachineOf=frontend@%i.service
```

This works fine, but it took me ages to get to this stage, because if I change the `etcdctl` line to this:

```
etcdctl set /services/frontend/%i "${COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:${PORT}" --ttl 60; \
```

Then it doesn't work - it ends up setting a value like `100.45.218.3:`, with no port. Along the way I spent a lot of time playing with different uses of the `$PORT` variable, and I have no idea why the configuration I settled on works. At one point I had this in the script:

```
echo hi $PORT; \
echo "hi $PORT"; \
echo hi ${PORT}; \
echo "hi ${PORT}"; \
```

And got journal logs like this:

```
Aug 17 01:05:07 core-01 bash[53694]: hi 32769
Aug 17 01:05:07 core-01 bash[53694]: hi 32769
Aug 17 01:05:07 core-01 bash[53694]: hi
Aug 17 01:05:07 core-01 bash[53694]: hi
```

Essentially my question is: what's going on here? This flies in the face of how I understand `{}` to work in bash scripts. And why can I use curlies on the `COREOS_PRIVATE_IPV4` variable (which is exported from `/etc/environment`, but not for `PORT`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is documented in [systemd.service(1)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html). `${PORT}` is expanded by systemd. To pass the `$` to the shell you need to write `$$`, so `$${PORT}`. The important line is this:

> To pass a literal dollar sign, use "$$". Variables whose value is not known at expansion time are treated as empty strings.

Comment: Thanks for that! That makes sense now, I didn't notice that variables could be substituted by systemd differently to during execution of the script itself...

Answer (score 1):

1. if the content of PORT comes from some other bash variable you would be dealing with an `indirect reference` then please try:

   ```
   ${!PORT}
   ```
2. I assume you are sure your shell is Bash

Comment: Thanks for the response!

1. `PORT` comes from a line in the script `export PORT=$(docker ...);`

2. CoreOS ships with bash 4.2

Comment: did you try `${!PORT}` in your script??

Comment: I did, and it seems to give the same result (an empty string).